# how to set record by update query sql vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have table and i want to set value if cell=null then set record by textbox .
here is my table

```
--------------------
col1| col2| Note
1       2    aaa
5       5    (*)  set record Only here if cell is Null
42     14
47     55   
------------------
```

here is my code and my problem is the query write for every cell that is Null and I want to write only for next cell that before it is not null

```
con.Open()
query = " update firealarm set Note=@Note where Note Is Null"
Dim command As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(query, con)
command.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Note", SqlDbType.NVarChar))
command.Parameters("@Note").Value = Notebox.Text.ToString
command.ExecuteNonQuery()
con.Close()
```

Comment: you are vulnerable to sql injection

Comment: `query = " update firealarm set Note=@Note where Note is Null"

Answer (score 2):

First, let's fix the immediate problem: in SQL `NULL` is not equal to anything, including other `NULL`s, so `Note<>Null` is true for all rows. To address this problem, SQL has special operators `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL`. Using `where Note is not NULL` will fix the problem.

A bigger problem remains, though: your program is vulnerable to SQL Injection attack. To fix this problem in Visual Basic see [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/542510/335858).

**Edit:** (in response to an edit of the question)

> I want to write only for next cell that before it is `not null`

The "next cell" implies some *order* of cells in the table. Since table rows should be treated as an unordered collection, let's assume that you would like to order by `col1`, the way the data is ordered in your example.

The query condition becomes much bigger for this:

```
UPDATE f
SET f.Note=@Note
FROM firealarm f
WHERE Note Is Null
  AND NOT EXIST (
    SELECT * FROM firealarm ff WHERE ff.col1 < f.col1 AND ff.Note IS NULL
  )
```

The new `WHERE` condition says that the update needs to be done on the cell with the lowest `col1` and `NULL` value in the `Note` column.

Comment: can you be my mentor? :3

Comment: @dasblinkenlight ----query = " update firealarm set Note=@Note where Note Is  Null"---- the problem is set records in all cells that is null , i want to set only next cell after not null and keep all null cell

Comment: @Subrati you need `where Note is not NULL`. After that add `query.Parameters.Add("@Note", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = Notebox.Text` to set the value of the `@Note` parameter.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I have already added but it does not give me what I want ,it gives value for all null cells

Answer (score 0):

For updating exact row you need more conditions in the `WHERE` statement

```
UPDATE firealarm SET Note=@Note 
WHERE Note IS NULL 
AND Col1 = @ValueOfCol1
AND Col2 = @ValueOfCol2
```

`vb.net` code

```
con.Open()
Dim query As String = <![CDATA[UPDATE firealarm SET Note=@Note 
WHERE Note IS NULL
AND Col1 = @ValueOfCol1
AND Col2 = @ValueOfCol2]]>.Value
Dim command As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(query, con)
With command.Parameters
    .Add(New SqlParameter With {.ParameterName = "@Note",
                                .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar,
                                .Value = Notebox.Text})
    .Add(New SqlParameter With {.ParameterName = "@ValueOfCol1",
                                .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int,
                                .Value = 5})
    .Add(New SqlParameter With {.ParameterName = "@ValueOfCol2",
                                .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int,
                                .Value = 5})
End With
command.ExecuteNonQuery()
con.Close()
```

Or use value of identity column if your table have this

Answer (score 0):

Try this query,it will update just first row which is null

```
WITH UpdateList_view AS 
( SELECT TOP 1 * from  Fire alarm     
  Where NOTE is Null ) 


update UpdateList_view 
set Note=@Note
```

Comment: How sure you can be that updated row will be needed one?

Comment: No cant assure,without few more details,hope there must be some id columns